# How to print python logger info level

Tags: python-3.7

I want to run a python3.7 script on the command line and have logger.info() messages show up on stdout the same way logger.warning() does.

Here's my code:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO))
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
print(logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO))
logger.info('my info message')
logger.warn('my warning message')
```

Expected output:

```
False
True
my info message
my warning message
```

Actual output:

```
False
True
my warning message
```

example: https://repl.it/repls/UnknownWideeyedPhase

Answer (score 0):

In the example above you need to define a Stream-Handler to tell the logger where to send the logs to. If you want to send them to stdout (console output), just add

```
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout)
```

For further details concerning logging configuration, I propose reading the documentation [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging)

P.S. you should use `logger.warning` as `logger.warn` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved in [Logging setLevel is being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109355/logging-setlevel-is-being-ignored)

But following the resolution:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO))
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')
print(logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO))
logger.info('my info message')
logger.warning('my warning message')
```