# Why does logger.info() only appear after calling logging.info()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am using Python 3.6.4. I first encountered an issue where `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` was ignored, and came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55623870/3927314), which confused me and gave rise to this question.

Given the code below,

> **1. Why does `logging.info('2')` get printed in Snippet 2, but not in 1?** (Isn't `logging.info()`  is a module level function? Why does naming a logger affect this call?)
>
> **2. Why does `logger.info('3')` get printed, but not `logger.info('1')`?**

### Snippet 1

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger('foo')  # named logger
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> logger.info('1')
>>> logging.info('2')  # prints nothing
>>> logger.info('3')
INFO:foo:3
```

### Snippet 2

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger()  # no name
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> logger.info('1')
>>> logging.info('2')  # printed
INFO:root:2
>>> logger.info('3')
INFO:root:3
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you point out, the difference between the snippets is in how you get the `logger` object:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('foo')
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

The key thing is that, in the second case, you are getting the "root" logger. In the first case, on the other hand, you are getting a "sublogger" of the root called `foo`.

Now, let's go step by step.

```
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Here you set the level of the logger. In the first case, you are setting the level for the logger `foo`. On creation, new loggers do not have a level, so they process every message; here you are saying that only messages with severity `INFO` or higher should be processed. But, in the second case, `logger` is the root logger. The confusing bit here is that, unlike new loggers, the root logger default level is `WARN`, so nothing below that level is processed unless you change it. So, after this line:

- In the first snippet, the root logger is set to `WARN` level, and the `foo` logger is set to `INFO` level.
- In the second snippet, the root logger is set to `INFO` level.

```
logger.info('1')
```

First logged line. Here you have the same behavior in both cases. The message is `INFO`, and `logger` is set to that severity, so the message is processed. However, you do not have any handler set in `logger`, so nothing is actually done with the message.

```
logging.info('2')
```

Now this is more interesting. What is important here is what `logging.info` actually does, which is not the same as if you call the `info` method of the root logger object:

> Log a message with severity 'INFO' on the root logger. If the logger has
> no handlers, call basicConfig() to add a console handler with a pre-defined
> format.

So, this function will make a console handler by itself if no handlers are registered for the root logger. So any message received by the root logger or subloggers will now be printed to console. In the first case, however, turns out that the root logger has still its default severity filter, `WARN`, so the console handler is registered, but the message is actually ignored. In the second case, though, you set the severity level of the root logger to `INFO`, so the message is processed and printed by the console handler.

```
logger.info('3')
```

Hopefully this should make sense now. Now you have a console handler attached to the root logger. In the first case, `logger` is the `foo` logger, and its severity is set to `INFO`, so the message is processed and, since it is a sublogger of the root logger, it is printed by the console handler registered for that one. In the second case, you are just logging to the root logger, which has `INFO` severity and the registered console handler.

Note that in the last line of the first case, the message processed by the `foo` logger is handled by the handler registered in the root logger even though the severity level of the root logger is `WARN`. Log handlers are not responsible for filtering by severity, that is done by the logger itself, so once a logger has decided that a message should be processed, it is handled by all its handlers and the handlers from parent loggers. This is a very useful feature, since it allows you to have a higher system-level log level and a lower one for specific modules that you are more interested in (e.g. for debugging or simply reporting).

EDIT: As pointed out by [@kilgoretrout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2238779/kilgoretrout), replacing the first `logger.info(1)` with `logger.warning(1)` *does* print `1` in both cases. While it is still true that the logger will not have any handler configured in that case, in Python 3.2 a [`lastResort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort) log handler was introduced to prevent a previous error message you would get in this case indicating that no handlers could be found for the logger. The last resort handler, which by default is a simple printing handler with warning level, is used when no handlers can be found for a message in the logger hierarchy. It can be configured as a module-level variable, and it does not affect the configuration of the logger objects.

Comment: Can you explain why any logger (root or child) will log a `warn()` without setting up a handler? i.e., if you change `logger.info('1')` to `logger.warn('1')` in both snippets you'll see "1" printed. Your explanation for `logger.info('1')` line is "...you do not have any handler set in logger, so nothing is actually done with the message." But, it seems there is *some* kind of handler, since we can get the warn "1" printed, it's just that the root's default warn severity is seems to be used until we execute `basicConfig()` (whether directly or indirectly by calling `logging.info(...)`.

Comment: @kilgoretrout Good point. Apparently a [`logging.lastResort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort) handler was introduced in 3.2, which will be used if a message processed by a logger does not find any handler in the logger hierarchy. It's just a simple printing handler with warning level. This prevents the message "no handlers could be found for logger [...]" if you try to log without any configuration. This is a module-level configuration, and it does not really affect the configuration of the logger objects otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43123658/1467082) on that post:

> If you don't configure logging with any handlers (as in your post - you only configure a level for your logger, but no handlers anywhere), you'll get an internal handler "of last resort" which is set to output just the message (with no other formatting) at the `WARNING` level.

Your level is currently *less than* `WARNING`, so it is not output. This changes with a call to `basicConfig()` which you may/should do explicitly, otherwise it's not being handled until it's called from `logging.info` (or one of the other convenience functions).

The documentation observes this:

> **Note** The above module-level convenience functions, which delegate to the root logger, call `basicConfig()` to ensure that at least one handler is available. Because of this, they should not be used in threads, in versions of Python earlier than 2.7.1 and 3.2, unless at least one handler has been added to the root logger before the threads are started. In earlier versions of Python, due to a thread safety shortcoming in `basicConfig()`, this can (under rare circumstances) lead to handlers being added multiple times to the root logger, which can in turn lead to multiple messages for the same event.