# Why don't I get any output for logger.info

Tags: python-3.x, logging

```
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def start():
    print(f"logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO) 20: {logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO)}")
    print(f"logger.getEffectiveLevel(): {logger.getEffectiveLevel()}")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    print(f"logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) done")
    print(f"logger.getEffectiveLevel(): {logger.getEffectiveLevel()}")
    print(f"logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO) 20: {logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO)}")
    logger.info('info message')
    logger.warning('warn message')
    logger.error('error message')
    logger.critical('critical message')

start()
```

Why doesn't this log:

`info message`

I know root logger starts logging at logging.WARNING, but I suppose I've modified the effective level of my logger, right ?

Unrelated: Why is logger module designed to be so clumsy to use ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`

```
import logging
  
# create logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# rest of the code
```

Result:

```
logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO) 20: True
logger.getEffectiveLevel(): 20
logger.getEffectiveLevel(): 20
logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO) 20: True
INFO:__main__:info message
WARNING:__main__:warn message
ERROR:__main__:error message
CRITICAL:__main__:critical message
```

For your code to work you should add a handler

```
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But my question was not how to get INFO message logged, my question was why it is not getting logged with the code I am experimenting with.

Comment: An explanation for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/43123658/2834978

Comment: Thanks @LMC That is the answer indeed.